# Remove string after finding specific character

Tags: regex, perl

My Perl program only removes the last three characters of the string. Currently, I am finding a way to find the count including `+` and remove using `substr` or if there is any built-in function in Perl.

```
open my $hfile, $ARGV[0] or die "Can't open $ARGV[0] for reading: $!";
while( my $line = <$hfile> ){
   if ($line =~ /+/){
       $line = substr($line, -3);
       print $line;
   }
}
close $hfile;
```

Input file

```
hello_aba+32
gaww_ajnd_arhb+176
ajnbjsdsjn+416
```

Output file

```
hello_aba
gaww_ajnd_arhb
ajnbjsdsjn
```

Comment: you want to remove from "+" to the end of line? Or "+" and up to 3 chars following? Or the 3 last characters if the line contains a "+"?

Comment: "+" to the end of line

Comment: So it's `s/\+.*//`

Comment: Your code is missing a `{`, your file handle (that you open) is called `$stack`, not `$hfile`. Don't post code that you have not tried to run exactly how it is. You will also have line ending issues if you delete the end of the line blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove anything after "+" in your lines, use a [substitution regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick#Search-and-replace):

```
$line =~ s/\+.*// && print $line;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic task for a perl one-liner. I would use some caution when deleting after a control character. First off, anchor it to the end of line. Second, make sure only expected characters are deleted.

Assuming the characters to delete 1) does not include plus-signs `+`, 2) does not include newlines, I would write:

```
perl -pe' s/\+[^+\n]*$// ' file.txt
```

`[^ ... ]` is a character class, and it is negated with `^` to mean "match any character that does not match what is inside".

While `+` following nothing is probably considered a literal plus and not a meta character, I think escaping it `\+` is proper, and prevents future update errors. Assuring that the rest of the line does not contain `+` assures that any extra plus signs do not cause us to lose data, e.g.

```
if foo = 2, then foo + bar = 4+123
#                    ^ first  ^ second
```

Adding `$` for end of line will anchor the match to the end of the line. This will prevent any extra `+` signs to mess up our input. Otherwise it would delete between the two first plus signs found.

Since we do not delete the line endings `\n`, the file structure remains unchanged.

Demonstration:

```
$ cat plus.txt
hello_aba+32
gaww_ajnd_arhb+176
ajnbjsdsjn+416
foo + bar = 3+123

$ perl -pe' s/\+[^+\n]*$//' plus.txt
hello_aba
gaww_ajnd_arhb
ajnbjsdsjn
foo + bar = 3
```

If you want to change the input file, you can either use redirection:

```
$ perl -pe ..... > newfile.txt
```

Or add the `-i` switch to perform in-place edit:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e ....
```

(`.bak` will create a backup file with extension `.bak`). Note that the original file is overwritten, so use caution.